# How to Skip Records of MySQL table using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use PHP to get MySQL to skip the first 5 entries into a table called "blog"  and then list the 6th to 10th entry.

What I mean is if there is 10 entries in the table "blog" with "id" -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, I want PHP to skip all entries of "id" 6 to 10 and then echo "id" 1 to 5.

This is currently the code I have. How should I edit this to implement that?

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC;";
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIMIT` is used for exactly this. Its usage is described in the [article on `SELECT` in the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

```
SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```